# Convert sql query column values into a list with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, list, sqlalchemy

I have a table **list_test** in my database that looks like this

```
ID   ListColumn   CategoryColumn1    CategoryColumn2   CategoryColumn3
1    List1        Meat               Dairy             Bread
2    List2        Fish               Bread             Candy
```

I am sending in a variable called **"currentList"** (with value List1) from my frontend via axios to my backend function `load_category_list()`
I then take the variable **"currentList"** and filter out the row List1 with my query.

I then want to take that row (in this case row 1) and input the values of the different categories into a list. 
I.e I want to create a list: **category_list = (Meat, Dairy, Bread)**

Though I am having trouble iterating through the queryobject to create the category_list.
The reason why I want to do this is because the I will not know exactly how many CategoryColumns every list will have so I can't specify them.

**This is my code**

*Class definition and SQLALchemy session*

```
class list_class(Base):
    __tablename__ = "list_test"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    list = Column(String)
    foodcategory1 = Column(String)
    foodcategory2 = Column(String)
    foodcategory3 = Column(String)


def  loadsession():
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    #metadata = Base.metadata
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    return session

session = loadsession()
```

*Part taking care of POST request and filtering table*

```
@app.route("/load_category_list", methods = ['POST'])
def load_category_list():
    reply_json = request.get_json()
    list_reply = reply_json["currentList"]
    categorylist_query = session.query(list_class).filter(list_class.list == list_reply).all()
```

If I run the following in **load_category_list()**

```
 for var in categorylist_query:
    print(var)
```

Then I get 
<**main**.list_class object at 0x05484970>

Though if I run

```
category_list = []    
for var in categorylist_query:
   for v in var:
      category_list.append(v)
print(category_list)
```

Then I get "TypeError: 'list_class' object is not iterable"

I tried running iter() on object and tried the examples specified here https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-make-a-class-iterable-create-iterator-class-for-it/
but I can't make it work.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a simpler way to achieve what you need is by making use of a SQL `ARRAY` directly in your query (if you database supports it). This can be implemented with sqlalchemy as:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

categorylist_query = session.query(
    list_class.list,
    func.array(
        list_class.foodcategory1,
        list_class.foodcategory2,
        list_class.foodcategory3
    ).label('food_categories')
).filter(list_class.list == list_reply)
```

This has the additional benefit of passing the load to the database. Later you can iterate over the results in a simpler way.

```py
for var in categorylist_query:
    print(var.list, var.food_categories)
```

On a side not, you cannot iterate over a row like that, if your intention is to access each column.

Comment: Thanks, that helped :)